# How to include image in background

Tags: graphics

When inserting a figure into a TeX document is there an easy way to make it appear behind the text?

Comment: Is the position dependent on the content? Have you looked at the `background` package?

Comment: Consider searching under [tag:watermark].

Comment: Are you referring to a single image on a particular page or do you want some image in the background of all pages?

Comment: Part a specific image needs to underlay the text on one page.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can put an image into zero width and zero height/depth box, so TeX will just runs over it.  Also, you probably want to lower the figure since normally the reference point is at the bottom.

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \raisebox{-\totalheight}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[width=4in]{book}}}%
\lipsum[1-2]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really good, thanks.  The image is opaque right?  Just want to be sure this puts it in the background not on top.  Could the same trick put the graphic over the foreground?

Comment: The image is opaque.  To put it on the foreground, just typeset it after the text

Comment: There is easier way. Just add negative space after the picture: `\includegraphics[height=1\textheight]{picture} \vspace*{-1\textheight}` (assuming the picture is the first thing on page)

Comment: I am not sure it is easier :)

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package. Initially, you use the `pages=some` option, so no background is initially used. Then on the page(s) in which you desire the image, you use the `\BackImage` command; its optional argument passes options to `\includegraphics`, and the mandatory argument contains the name of the image file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pages=some,scale=1,angle=0,opacity=0.7]{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\BackImage[2][scale=1]{%
\BgThispage
\backgroundsetup{
  contents={\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\BackImage[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}% image on page 1
\lipsum[4-22]
\BackImage[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}% image on page 4
\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the available keys for `\backgroundsetup` you can easily change the attributes (opacity, position, scale, angle) of the included image.

In the case of a single image, it's enough to set `contents` to be the `\includegraphics`, `pages=some` and to use `\BgThisPage` for the page in which the image should be included.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  angle=0,
  opacity=0.7,
  contents={
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=4cm]{example-image-a}}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]
\BgThispage
\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You could also do this with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgfpages,tikz,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node[anchor=center] at (current page.center){%
        \pgfimage{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

which puts the background image only on the required page:

[image: background picture with <code>tikz</code>]

Or you might prefer to use `wallpaper` which offers the same functionality, as well as a way to repeat the image on every page:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{wallpaper,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]
\ThisCenterWallPaper{1}{example-image-b}
%\CenterWallPaper{1}{example-image-b}% use this instead if you want the background repeated


\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image: background image on single page with <code>wallpaper</code>]