# Send a particular figure to the back

Tags: floats, margins

I am writing a double-columned article.
I am having a problem that one particular figure covers some of the text above and another figure across the column. See following picture:

[image]

I did a lot of search, but all talk about making the figure "background". Well I don't want to make it background, I would just like to "send it to the back".

How can I make this particular figure "under" the text above, and the figure across the column? Thanks a lot.

Here is my figure insertion code:

```
\vspace{-1cm}
\begin{figure}[h]
\hspace{-0.9cm}
\vspace{-1cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{../figures/lin_regression.png}
\caption{Regressions of phase rolls.}
\label{fig_lin_regression}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: latex doesn't have a layered output you need to set backgrouund things before foreground. But why have you got negative spacing? especially the negative space _before_ the figure is very odd as if the figure floats to another position the negative space will make the next paragraph of text overprint the previous one,

Comment: This may be of interest: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156903/105447

Comment: I'd like to have a lager figure, but the margin of the figure is relatively large. So if I have a large figure and if I have a non-negtive spacing, then the figure goes out of boundary.

Comment: @gusbrs Yeah.... but like I said in the thread, I do not want to make my image background......

Comment: but negative vspace is just forcing the problem you have. you have 2cm of negative space before the figure, are you saying that the png image has a 2cm white space at the top? in any case you should use the `clip` option to trim the figure  not use negative space

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, I guess clip is the solution then.

Comment: unrelated but don't use `[h]` it makes it highly likely that the figure floats to the end of the document, usually latex warns and changes it to `[ht]` but `[htp]` is better

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK. Thanks David. Pleas post your clip suggestion as answer. I quickly tried it, and it gives me what I want.

Comment: Beside to clip properly the image, do not use `scale=0.27` but `width=\linewidth` that  ensure that you image will fit perfectly in the column, whatever the original image size, and without using any `\hspace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negative spacing is *forcing* the overprinting, Also since `figure` is a float, the `\vspace` before the figure is completely wrong as if the figure floats the `\vspace` will still be in that place and cause the following text to overprint the preceding text.

If there is a white margin in the png, trim it with an external graphics editor or use the `trim` or `clip` options to `\includegraphics` also it is almost always best to include `p` or it is highly likely the float will go to the end of the document, so

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics[scale=0.27,clip= 20 20 500 500 ]{../figures/lin_regression.png}
\caption{Regressions of phase rolls.}
\label{fig_lin_regression}
\end{figure}
```

using whatever clip box coordinates make sense in your case.